# LIRC partial read 8 bytes

Tags: raspberry-pi3, debian-based, lirc

I tried to create my own universal remote using my Raspberry Pi 3 with newest Raspbian. After constructing little receiver and transmitter [(tutorial I followed)](https://www.piddlerintheroot.com/ir-blaster-lirc/) and connecting everything up I got this message when trying to receive IR.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe lirc_rpi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo kill $(pidof lircd)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
Using driver devinput on device /dev/lirc0
Trying device: /dev/lirc0
Using device: /dev/lirc0
Partial read 8 bytes on /dev/lirc0pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer from @leamas points me to the right direction but changing `driver = devinput` to `driver = default` in `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf` does not help. But with this command I get it to run:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc0
```

With `sudo adduser pi video`, logout and login, I do not need `sudo` for the command.

Answer (score 2):

This line actually makes no sense:

```
Using driver devinput on device /dev/lirc0
```

The devinput driver requires a device in the /dev/input directory, whereas the *default* driver (silly name...) uses a /dev/lirc* device like */dev/lirc0*.

So, to get rid of this error you need to either change the device to a /dev/input device or change the driver to *default*. My gut feeling is to go for the latter alternative, but guts are not always trustworthy.

Also, you might have a bumpy road ahead even if you should get rid of this particular error. The configuration file you are using belongs to the 0.9.0 lirc version, an ancient piece of software seven years old. Upstream is at 0.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I changed the following two lines in `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf`

```
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0
```

And then, to get it to run...

```
$ sudo mode2
```